# Office 365 e-mails filtered to junk

Tags: email, office365

I'm having some issues with an Office 365 user's e-mails.

All e-mails from one particular user which is also part of the same domain, are being filtered to "Junk" and being marked as spam.

I have tried the following;

1. Creating a rule that filters all e-mails from the user into inbox
2. On the default Spam rule that affects the entire domain set the user up to never have the e-mails sent to the Junk folder
3. Allowed all e-mails from within the domain to go into the inbox and not be marked as Spam/Junk
4. One the affected user turned off e-mail processing so no e-mails will be sent to the Junk folder

None of the above have worked and the e-mails are still being sent to the Junk folder.

They land in the inbox for about 5 or so seconds and then are thrown into the Junk folder and marked as Spam.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you see an Infobar notification above the message saying why the message has been filtered out? It might mention: (1) "Outlook Junk E-mail filter” - need to troubleshoot your Junk E-mail settings, (2) "a junk filter other than the Outlook Junk E-mail filter” - need to troubleshoot the virus scanner or Junk E-mail filter on client or server, (3) Otherwise this was caused by a rule or done manually.

Comment: Question: Are you or the Exchange server using [SmartScreen filters](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2016/09/01/deprecating-support-for-smartscreen-in-outlook-and-exchange/) with [confidence level](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995744.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: I have adjusted the SCL level on the "Junk mail" Rule that covers our O365 domain. Waiting to hear if this has resolved the issue.

Comment: I have added an answer, in case this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [outlook.office365.com](https://outlook.office365.com) on the web and login using your Office365 account. Click on the cog ➔ *Options*. Then look for *Mail* ➔ *Accounts* ➔ *Block or allow*. On this section you will be able to add addresses to the Safe Senders and Recipients list.

[image: office365 options]

Comment: I tried adding both members to the safe senders section on outlook. Unfortunately this did not resolve the issue. I have changed the SCL level on outlook to see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: Adjusting the SCL threshold hasnt worked. E-Mails are still being put into the junk folder. I created a rule on the affected users inbox to copy all emails from the sender and to put them into the inbox, the rule didn't work as it then sent all e-mails to the clutter folder

Answer (score 1):

Check on the Exchange server the [SmartScreen filters](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2016/09/01/deprecating-support-for-smartscreen-in-outlook-and-exchange/) and the
matching [confidence level](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995744.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

The SCL level on the "Junk mail" Rule that covers your O365 domain may need
adjustment.

Comment: I reduced the SCL level on the Junk Mail to 4 and the emails were still being sent straight to junk.